# Set a slider value based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, slider

I have Excel files to populate on a monthly basis.

I've automated much of this task using an embedded ODBC connection that runs a stored procedure.

The files contain sliders and I've been unable to automatically set the slider value based on data that is pulled through from the stored procedure into a hidden sheet.

My thought was to use a macro to look at the specific cell value once the data has refreshed, and then move the slider automatically until it matches the specified value.

Comment: Since there are so many sliders then which slider would you like to work with?

Comment: Hi - I managed to solve the issue by using a different method - thanks for the assistance though

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub Slider1_Change()

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Me.Slider1.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work - it looks like the slider is set up as a form control.  Thanks for the assistance though.  I've managed to answer this question using a different method.